# Is it possible to update text from a ToastNotification on screen?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

With the following method I create a toast and show it. The toast doesn't show the new text when I change the text in the else section. Is it possible to update the text on screen without showing a new toast?

```
private static ToastNotification ToastNotificationInstance;

internal static void Show(string message)
{
    if (ToastNotificationInstance == null)
    {
        ToastTemplateType template = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText01;
        XmlDocument document = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(template);

        XmlNodeList text = document.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        text[0].AppendChild(document.CreateTextNode(message));

        ToastNotificationInstance = new ToastNotification(document);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(ToastNotificationInstance);
    }
    else
    {
        XmlNodeList text = ToastNotificationInstance.Content.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        text[0].AppendChild(ToastNotificationInstance.Content.CreateTextNode(message));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing the  ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(ToastNotificationInstance); method in your else part. which is required to show the notification.

Comment: This creates an exception: `The notification has already been posted`.

Comment: the error is self explanatory. ToastNotification object cannot show notification if it is already posted once.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to update the text of the posted toast to show new info while it is showing?

Comment: Are you using ToastNotificationInstance in anywhere else in the code? I think declaring a static variable like that is not required. Declare itself in the Show method & remove the null checking